How to pass data to nested navigation of Jetpack Compose Type-Safe Navigation?
I have two nested graph group and group details.
Group details graph has 3 screens, which need userId.
How do I pass data to the nested navigation? Without directly calling the first screen or other screens in group details graph, my use case wants to pass a string to all screens of GroupDetailGraph nested navigation graph. This means I'm calling GroupDetailGraph(userId = "123") from the root(group) graph and want to give the user ID to all screens of GroupDetailGraph.
If you are saying don't call GroupDetailGraph with userId and call every screen with userId, then please tell what is the actual need of nested navigation. Attachedthe Google Doc image.
Can you please tell me what I didn't understand from the google doc?
see code below
Data class:
    @Serializable
    data class GroupDetailGraph(val groupId: String? = null)
    
    @Serializable
    data class GroupDetail(val groupId: String? = null)

//Here I have two more screens which also need groupId.

Navigation logic: This is how I am navigating to my nested graph:
rootNavController.navigate(
    GroupDetailGraph(
        groupId = "123"
    )
)

Nested Graph: Here’s how I set up my nested navigation graph:
   fun NavGraphBuilder.groupDetailNavGraph(rootNavController: NavHostController) {
    navigation<GroupDetailGraph>(
        startDestination = GroupDetail()
    ) {
        composable<GroupDetail> { backStackEntry ->
            // If I call directly navigate(GroupDetail(groupId = "123"), I can use this way.
            val group: GroupDetail = backStackEntry.toRoute()
            GroupDetailsScreen(rootNavController = rootNavController, groupId = group.groupId)
        }
          //Here I have two more screens which also need groupId.

    }
}


I had the same problem and what I did was to not define the graph as a extension function but rather as a composable in the NavHost:
composable<GroupDetailGraph>() {

}

Then I created a composable function in another file which there I defined a NavHost for my graph to host the screens:
@Composable
fun GroupDetailGraphScreens(
     args: GroupDetailGraph
) {
      NavHost(
          navController = rememberNavController(),
          startDestination = ...
      ) {
          // screens
      }
}

Then in the composable<GroupDetailGraph> block you can receive the data and call the GroupDetailGraphScreen() composable function and pass the data.
    composable<GroupDetailGraph>() {
         navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.toRoute<GroupDetailGraph>()?.let { args ->
               GroupDetailGraphScreens(args) 
    }
}

With this solution all your screens can receive the args or data all at once.

Thanks Arsham, I also think about this solution first but this is like a quick fix, my use case is a little different, I'll also need those nested screens from another part, with this solution I have to manage another navController which will make this more complex. I think it's better I should call every screen with data, what do you think?

@IYCS Yeah another NavHost is another overhead. It's simpler to call the screens directly but if you need to do it frequently in your code then having a nested graph is meaningless and is just for beautifying the code.
